# Want to Modify/MiTM for RTP traffic between two interface

Tags: linux, routes, rtp, iptables, sniffing

I am running linux machine between two IP Phone with Two NIC card's. all of the traffic passthroug between eth0 and eth1 should move through TCP/IP stack.currently,IP-forwarding is enabled in linux and traffic route directly at Kernel level. If I am doing port forwarding using IPtables, I can get the traffic in TCP/IP stack but I dont want to perform port forwarding. Every time traffic is having different port, its difficult to map the port again with its original port.

Is there any other mechanism, I can get every packet in tcp/IP stack without port forwarding either using some routing or creating virtual interface/loopback interface?